# SP 2010 - Search Core Results Webpart Ajax Options not working?

Tags: web-part, search, search-results, ajax, paging

I'm trying to enable ajax on search core results webpart so that the pagination can be realized in an asynchronous manner. But this is not working. Is this normal? Do you succeed to configure search core results and paging webparts to work asynchronously?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided particular problem which you're facing. What have you tried, which options values have you set up, and what errors (in ULS or on the page) or visual results have you got?

Comment: In fact it is just not doing asynchronous calls. When I click on a page number, I get a normal postback.

Comment: Anyone can help on that? Did you already see the ajax on search core results working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that there are two separate webparts in Search Center: Core Results Web Part and Search Paging Web Part. And while Core Results Web Part supports asynchronous functioning, the paging webpart doesn't seem to have any ajax-related properties.

Actually, CoreResultsWebPart is inherited from DataFormWebPart - that's why we've got the Ajax parameters section, and the DataFormWebPart undoubtedly does support asynchronous postbacks.

So I assume if you want to configure AJAX paging, the only option could be to give up the Search Paging Web Part, and try to implement paging through XSLT. Probably it will be not very cool paging, but it will be asynchronous.

To implement paging using XSLT, you have to add some XSLT code to CoreResultsWebPart, as described in the following article:

- http://www.mstechblogs.com/shailaja/paging-for-search-results-xslt-alternative-of-search-paging-webpart/

I haven't tried this solution myself, but the idea seems logically strong :)

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look to this link and try several approaches.

Comment: One more question, in the link you gave me, the author seems to add params at the top of the xsl section. Do you know where he will get the values for these parameters? Thanks.

Comment: Usually they're passed through ParameterBindings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806155.aspx

Answer (score 1):

..."And while Core Results Web Part supports asynchronous functioning".  I believe this is the problem right there.  The initial load of CRWP does indeed work when asynchronous is turned on, but refresh or automatic refresh does not.  The asynchronous refresh functions send the part into loading mode and never return.